# Best Way to Access sqlite For Prolonged Periods

Tags: shell, sqlite

Okay, so I have a shell script that uses an sqlite database for storing data. However, it's a long running script that runs a lot of small queries over time.

Currently I'm calling `sqlite3 'my.db' 'SELECT * FROM foo'` or similar for every query, however I don't expect that this is terribly efficient, as sqlite will have to re-open the database each time (unless it sneakily keeps them open for a while?).

However, this also means that if I need to do any setup, such as specifying the timeout option, then I will need to do this every time I call `sqlite3` as well.

What I'm wondering is if there is some alternative way I can structure my script, for example opening the `sqlite3` process in the background in interactive mode and somehow feeding it with queries and grabbing responses. Is there a good, robust way to do this?

I've tried something along these lines, but I don't always know how many results a query will return (if any), so I end up having to do queries like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE bar=1; SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar=1`, so that I always get back at least one line with the number of results to expect, but this is no good if I (somehow) get more results than expected, as they will still be waiting when I run the next query.

Here's a shortened form of what I've tried (please forgive any typos, I'm sure to make some):

```
#!/bin/sh
mkfifo '/tmp/db_in'
mkfifo '/tmp/db_out'

# Create the sqlite process in the background (assume database setup already)
sqlite3 'my.db' </tmp/db_in >/tmp/db_out &

# Set connection parameters
echo '.timeout 1000' >/tmp/db_in

# Perform a query with count in first result
echo 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE bar=1;SELECT * FROM bar WHERE bar=1;' >/tmp/db_in
read results </tmp/db_out
while [ $results -gt 0 ]; do
    IFS='|'; read key value </tmp/db_out
    echo "$key=$value"

    results=$(($results - 1))
done
```

Is this along the right lines, or is there a better way to do this? I haven't been able to think of a way to get sqlite to return something at the end of output for each query, which would be a better way to do things I think. I know the echo option can be used to echo a query before its output, which I can at least use to make sure I don't read anything that's leftover from a previous query, but I really want to be able to handle arbitrary length results more correctly (without needing a count first, since this could go out of sync).

The only other alternative seems to be dumping results into a file, but as I may be handling a large number of queries I don't really want to be doing that; at least with FIFOs everything's still in memory.

[edit]
I've just noticed that some of the shells I try the above with close sqlite3 after writing to `db_in`, in those cases I think the fifos may need to be bound to a file-descriptor to keep them open. I'm not going to add this to the example just now as it makes it more complex, but if file-descriptors are used by a solution then it should probably be added for completeness.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this in a shell script? Have you considered using a different scripting language like Python where you don't need to go through the SQLite shell process?

Comment: I could, but I don't really want to be installing extra scripting languages if I don't have to; all of the machines I'll be using it with have a shell (albeit with some compatibility annoyances) and sqlite3 is already there, so I'd like to solve it in a shell script if I can; I'm sure there must be a way.

Comment: @Haravikk: I can appreciate that, but any system that has SQLite3 is likely to have at least Python 2.5, isn't it?  Python came with a SQLite API starting in 2.5 back in 2006.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it's also part of my requirements; I need it to be compatible, but I can't install anything that isn't absolutely necessary. Problem is I'm working with a lot of NAS units and the standardisation of them is… non-existent. I didn't realise how non-standards compliant a Linux distro could be till I started getting this work, some don't even support all the POSIX standard features, but have fairly recent kernel versions. Normally I like the challenge, other times… well you get the idea =)